# Unknown CMake command "CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX"

Tags: cmake, vmime

I tried running cmake to generate the build tools for linux on vmime with the latest source from git hub, it generated the following errors. Thoughts??

```
vmime$ /usr/local/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:
    CheckIncludeFileCxx
-- Build type: Debug
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:452 (CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX):
  Unknown CMake command "CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CMakeLists.txt at line 20, you have

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCxx)
```

This should be

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
                         ^^--- Uppercase
```

Once [`CheckIncludeFileCXX`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aCheckIncludeFileCXX) is properly included, the error on line 452 should also disappear, since the file defines the function `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX`.

It has probably only been tested on Windows; since Windows filenames are case-insensitive this would have worked.

Comment: that did it!! thanks. how do i change from the default debug build to release?

Comment: I think on Linux the default build is maybe Release.  Anyway, this is covered in [the FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_change_the_default_build_mode_and_see_it_reflected_in_the_GUI.3F)